# The number $2^{29}$ has exactly $9$ distinct digits. Which digit is missing?

Tags: contest-math

> The number $2^{29}$ has exactly $9$ distinct digits. Which digit is missing?

I came across this question in a math competition and I am looking for how to solve this question without working it out manually. Thanks.

Comment: The accepted answer only works for numbers in which every digit is distinct.  Is that supposed to be implied by "exactly 9 distinct digits"?  I interpret that as also allowing a 10-digit number with one duplicate.

Comment: "Has exactly 9 digits, all of which are distinct" might be more accurate.

Comment: @Brilliand: if we start with $2^{10}=1024$, it is not too hard to see that $2^{29}\approx500,000,000$. So, $2^{29}$ has $9$ digits.

Comment: I see how we know it has 9digits, $29\log 2=8.73$ but how does one know the digits are distinct ?

Comment: Just asking: Is it (the competition) SMO?

Comment: Yes its SMO(Junior) 2014.

Answer (score 46):

Oh its so easy, now that we follow the hint (thanks !)

$$\sum k_n  10^n \equiv \sum k_n \mod 9$$
the sum of all the digits is $\frac{9(9+1)}{2}\equiv 0 \mod 9$ so the sum of all but one $x$ is $\equiv -x \mod 9$

Now $$2^{29}\equiv -4 \mod 9$$ so $4$ is the missing digit.

Comment: I don't know what I'm missing out here, but will you be able to elaborate how to calculate $2^{29} \pmod 9$. Any hint will also suffice! Thanks for the answer, by the way!

Comment: You find the power of two mod 9, that is $2^n\equiv 1\pmod 9$ I forget what it is but then you divide it into 29.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. In fact, $2^{29}=2^{27} \times 4=(9-1)^9 \times 4$  which implies that $2^{29} \pmod 9= -4$

Comment: $+1$ to me it's like ingenius!

Answer (score 33):

A hint: Think about the remainder modulo $9$.

Comment: Oh its so easy, now that we follow the hint (thanks !)

Answer (score 12):

$2^{29}$ is not that big. You can just compute it. A fast launch point is to know that $2^{10}=1024$. So you just need to multiply $1024\cdot1024\cdot512$, which can be done by hand quickly in a competition.

Comment: It's about creative solution not answering it

Comment: Why would someone waste their time looking for a "creative solution" in a competition when computing it is not only fast but assured to work?

Comment: whats should we do? don't think on other methods to solve it?

Comment: @Karo If it is a competition and your goal is to finish and win, then yes. If you can identify an approach that will get you the answer quickly, what extra points do you get for being clever?

Comment: It's just beautiful to me that I prove that it should be digit x that is missing instead of computing the answer with calculator and finding out that digit x is missing. it's just personal feeling and I like mathematics to be like this.

Answer (score 2):

Let the number $N$ be represented by $9$ digits $d_i$ for $i=0,\dots,8$ so that 
$$N = \sum_{i=0}^{8} d_i  10^i$$ 
We first notice that 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{8} d_i  10^i \equiv \sum_i d_i \pmod{9}$$

Since only one digit is missing, this sum must be between 36 (with 9 missing) and 45 (with 0 missing). There are two cases to consider.  Either $\sum d_i \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$ or it is not.  In the first case, either 0 or 9 is the missing digit, since those are the only missing values for which $\sum_i d_i \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$, making the sum either 36 or 45. We can determine which is the value by looking at the sum $\pmod{8} = N \pmod{8}$: if this value is 4 then the sum is 36 and 9 is the missing digit.  If $N \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$, then the sum is 45 and 0 is the missing digit.

In the second case, we note that the sum of all but one digit $x$ is congruent to $-x \pmod{9}$.  Solving this congruence for $x$ gives the missing digit.

This addresses the case of an arbitrary $N$ for which $N \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$ which the accepted answer does not handle correctly.  Since I'm not yet allowed to comment or improve other answers by censors, I just constructed a new, complete answer.  Vote it up so in the future I can do this the right way.

Comment: This looks eerily similar to [Rene Schipperus' answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/819454).

Comment: It's not obvious how you can "look at the sum of digits mod 8", if all you know is that the number is $2^{29}$...