# The number $2^{29}$ has $9$ distinct digits. Find the missing digit without the use of a calculator.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> $2^{29}$ has $9$ distinct digits. Find the missing digit without the use of a calculator.

I've seen its solution before but I still don't understand it. Math novice here. A detailed answer will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @user291957 - I think that if the poster knew the answer to that question, then they would not be asking it here!

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Deleting the comment right now @Simon Rose

Comment: are you familiar with congruences/modular arithmetic @Paradox101

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819412/the-number-229-has-exactly-9-distinct-digits-which-digit-is-missing

Comment: yes i'm somewhat familiar with congruences

Comment: @Macavity I've seen that link before, but i don't really get it. Why should we take 2^29 mod 9?

Comment: @Macavity a little more elaboration needed. Thanks

Comment: 10^k = 1 (mod 9)

Comment: $10 = 1 \pmod 9 \implies 10\times 10 = 1\times 1 = 1 \pmod 9$ etc.  So $10^k = 1^k = 1 \pmod 9$. $$ $$ Alternately, note $10^k = 9999..999 + 1$ (where there are k-1 $9$s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $9$ distinct digits, one is missing from among $0$ to $9$.  The sum of all should give you $45$ (why?).  So if you had the sum of all digits, you could easily determine the missing one.

The next best thing is taking the number $\pmod 9$ - which  gives you the sum of digits $\pmod 9$ as $10^k = 1 \pmod 9$. To show this, let $2^{29} = \sum_{k=0}^9 a_k 10^k$. Then
$$2^{29} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^9a_k 10^k \equiv \sum_{k=0}^9a_k\pmod 9 $$

So in this case, this remainder gives you the answer, as you're looking for a one digit solution.

---

P.S. - This is a duplicate, so perhaps after studying it you could remove the Q.

Comment: Clever method; works for all nine digit numbers with no duplicate digits unless the missing digit is 0 or 9.